# How can I find element and how to write in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'quotes'
start_urls = [
    'https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/'
]

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    quote = response.css('p::text').extract()
    yield {'text': tittle}-- how to find element ?
```

I didn't have any idea about deep scraping and finding elements ..just basics  and i want to scrape all 150 quotes above url given..i can't find elements locating in developer tools..for atleast one quote in URl ,Can anyone suggest me..? URL= https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scrapy shell:

```
In [1]: fetch('https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/')
2021-08-07 13:19:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-08-07 13:19:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/> (referer: None)
```

```
In [4]: response.css('p:nth-child(n+6)::text').getall()
Out[4]:
['1. “The purpose of our lives is to be happy.” — ',
 '2. “Life is what happens when you’re busy making other plans.” — ',
 '3.\xa0“Get busy living or get busy dying.” —\xa0',
 '4. “You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.” — ',
 '5.\xa0“Many of life’s failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.”',
 '6.\xa0“If you want to live a happy life, tie it to a goal, not to people or things.”',
 '7.\xa0“Never let the fear of striking out keep you from playing the game.”',
 '8. “Money and success don’t change people; they merely amplify what is already there.” — ',
 '9.\xa0“Your time is limited, so don’t waste it living someone else’s life. Don’t be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people’s thinking.”\xa0',
 '10. “Not how long, but how well you have lived is the main thing.” — ',
 '11.\xa0“If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor.”\xa0',
 '12.\xa0“The whole secret of a successful life is to find out what is one’s destiny to do, and then do it.”',
 '13.\xa0“In order to write about life first you must live it.”',
 '14.\xa0“The big lesson in life, baby, is never be scared of anyone or anything.”',
 '15.\xa0“Sing like no one’s listening, love like you’ve never been hurt, dance like nobody’s watching, and live like it’s heaven on earth.” ',
 '16.\xa0“Curiosity about life in all of its aspects, I think, is still the secret of great creative people.”\xa0',
 '17.\xa0“Life is not a problem to be solved, but a reality to be experienced.”',
 '18. “The unexamined life is not worth living.” — ',
 '19. “Turn your wounds into wisdom.” — ',
 '20.\xa0“The way I see it, if you want the rainbow, you gotta put up with the rain.” —',
 '21. “Do all the good you can, for all the people you can, in all the ways you can, as long as you can.” — ',
 '22. “Don’t settle for what life gives you; make life better and build something.” — ',
 '23. “Everybody wants to be famous, but nobody wants to do the work. I live by that. You grind hard so you can play hard. At the end of the day, you put all the work in, and eventually it’ll pay off. It could be in a year, it could be in 30 years. Eventually, your hard work will pay off.” — ',
 '24. “Everything negative – pressure, challenges – is all an opportunity for me to rise.” — ',
 '25. “I like criticism. It makes you strong.” — ',
 '26. “You never really learn much from hearing yourself speak.” ― ',
 '27. “Life imposes things on you that you can’t control, but you still have the choice of how you’re going to live through this.” — ',
 '28. “Life is never easy. There is work to be done and obligations to be met – obligations to truth, to justice, and to liberty.” — ',
 '29. “Live for each second without hesitation.” — ',
 '30. “Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving.” — ',
 '31. “Life is really simple, but men insist on making it complicated.” —\xa0',
 '32. “Life is a succession of lessons which must be lived to be understood.” — ',
 '33.\xa0“Your work is going to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly satisfied is to do what you believe is great work. And the only way to do great work is to love what you do. If you haven’t found it yet, keep looking. Don’t settle. As with all matters of the heart, you’ll know when you find it.” — ',
 '34. “My mama always said, life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you’re gonna get.” — ',
 '35. “Watch your thoughts; they become words. Watch your words; they become actions. Watch your actions; they become habits. Watch your habits; they become character. Watch your character; it becomes your destiny.”—\xa0',
 '36. “When we do the best we can, we never know what miracle is wrought in our life or the life of another.” —\xa0',
 '37. “The healthiest response to life is joy.” —\xa0',
 '38. “Life is like a coin. You can spend it any way you wish, but you only spend it once.” —\xa0',
 '39. “The best portion of a good man’s life is his little nameless, unencumbered acts of kindness and of love.” —\xa0',
 '40. “In three words I can sum up everything I’ve learned about life: It goes on.” ― ',
 '41.\xa0“Life is ten percent what happens to you and ninety percent how you respond to it.” — ',
 '42.\xa0“Keep calm and carry on.” — ',
 '43.\xa0“Maybe that’s what life is… a wink of the eye and winking stars.” — ',
 '44.\xa0“Life is a flower of which love is the honey.” — ',
 '45. “Keep smiling, because life is a beautiful thing and there’s so much to ',
 ' about.” — ',
 '46.\xa0“Health is the greatest gift, contentment the greatest wealth, faithfulness the best relationship.” — ',
 '47.\xa0“You have brains in your head. You have feet in your shoes. You can steer yourself any direction you choose.” — ',
 '48.\xa0“Good friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.” — ',
 '49. “Life would be tragic if it weren’t funny.” — ',
 '50.\xa0“Live in the sunshine, swim the sea, drink the wild air.” — ',
 '51. “The greatest pleasure of life is love.” — ',
 '52.\xa0“Life is what we make it, always has been, always will be.” — ',
 '53.\xa0“Life’s tragedy is that we get old too soon and wise too late.” — ',
 '54.\xa0\xa0“',
 '55. “I’ve missed more than 9000 shots in my career. I’ve lost almost 300 games. 26 times I’ve been trusted to take the game winning shot and missed. I’ve failed over and over and over again in my life. And that is why I succeed.” – ',
 '56. “Every strike brings me closer to the next home run.” – ',
 '57. “The two most important days in your life are the day you are born and the day you find out why.” – ',
 '58. “Life shrinks or expands in proportion to one’s courage.” –',
 '59. “When I was 5 years old, my mother always told me that ',
 ' was the key to life.\xa0 When I went to school, they asked me what I wanted to be when I grew up.\xa0 I wrote down ‘happy’.\xa0 They told me I didn’t understand the assignment, and I told them they didn’t understand life.” – ',
 '60. “Too many of us are not living our dreams because we are living our fears.” – ',
 '61.\xa0\xa0“I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don’t intend to waste any of mine.” —',
 '62.\xa0“Live as if you were to die tomorrow. Learn as if you were to live forever.” —',
 '63.\xa0“If you live long enough, you’ll make mistakes. But if you learn from them, you’ll be a better person.” —',
 '64.\xa0“Life is short, and it is here to be lived.” —',
 '65.\xa0“The longer I live, the more beautiful life becomes.” —',
 '66.\xa0“Every moment is a fresh beginning.” —',
 '67.\xa0“When you cease to dream you cease to live.” —',
 '68.\xa0“If you spend your whole life waiting for the storm, you’ll never enjoy the sunshine.” —',
 '69.\xa0“Don’t cry because it’s over, smile because it happened.” —',
 '70.\xa0“If you can do what you do best and be happy, you’re further along in life than most people.” —',
 '71.\xa0“We should remember that just as a positive outlook on life can promote good health, so can everyday acts of kindness.” —',
 '72.\xa0“Don’t limit yourself. Many people limit themselves to what they think they can do. You can go as far as your mind lets you. What you believe, remember, you can achieve.” —',
 '73.\xa0\xa0“It is our choices that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.” —',
 '74.\xa0“If you’re not stubborn, you’ll give up on experiments too soon. And if you’re not flexible, you’ll pound your head against the wall and you won’t see a different solution to a problem you’re trying to solve.” —',
 '75. “The best way to predict your future is to create it.” — ',
 '76.\xa0“You must expect great things of yourself before you can do them.” —',
 '77.\xa0“Identity is a prison you can never escape, but the way to redeem your past is not to run from it, but to try to understand it, and use it as a foundation to grow.” —',
 '78.\xa0“There are no mistakes, only opportunities.” —',
 '79.\xa0“It takes 20 years to build a reputation and five minutes to ruin it. If you think about that, you’ll do things differently.” —',
 '80.\xa0“As you grow older, you will discover that you have two hands, one for helping yourself, the other for helping others.” —',
 '81. “Sometimes you can’t see yourself clearly until you see yourself through the eyes of others.” —',
 '82.\xa0“You must not lose faith in humanity. Humanity is an ocean; if a few drops of the ocean are dirty, the ocean does not become dirty.” —',
 '83.\xa0“All life is an experiment. The more experiments you make, the better.”\xa0– ',
 '84.\xa0“Here’s to the crazy ones, the misfits, the rebels, the troublemakers, the round pegs in the square holes … the ones who see things differently — they’re not fond of rules … You can quote them, disagree with them, glorify or vilify them, but the only thing you can’t do is ignore them because they change things … They push the human race forward, and while some may see them as the crazy ones, we see genius …” –',
 '85.\xa0“It had long since come to my attention that people of accomplishment rarely sat back and let things happen to them. They went out and happened to things.” – ',
 '86. “Throughout life people will make you mad, disrespect\xa0you\xa0and treat\xa0you\xa0bad.\xa0Let God deal with the things they\xa0do,\xa0cause\xa0hate in your heart\xa0will\xa0consume\xa0you\xa0too.” — ',
 '87. “Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment.”',
 '88. “Life is a dream for the wise, a game for the fool, a comedy for the rich, a tragedy for the poor.”\xa0',
 '89. “If you love life, don’t waste time, for time is what life is made up of.”\xa0',
 '90.\xa0When one door closes, another opens; but we often look so long and so regretfully upon the closed door that we do not see the one that has opened for us.\xa0',
 '91. “Never take life seriously. Nobody gets out alive anyway.” — ',
 '92. “Be happy for this moment. This moment is your life.”\xa0',
 '93.\xa0“Happiness is the feeling that power increases — that resistance is being overcome.” —\xa0',
 '94.\xa0“I have learned to seek my happiness by limiting my desires, rather than in attempting to satisfy them.” —\xa0',
 '95.\xa0',
 'The secret of happiness, you see is not found in seeking more, but in developing the capacity to enjoy less.”-',
 '96. “The more man meditates upon good thoughts, the better will be his world and the world at large.” —\xa0',
 '97.\xa0“The greatest blessings of mankind are within us and within our reach. A wise man is content with his lot, whatever it may be, without wishing for what he has not.”—\xa0',
 '98.\xa0“Happiness is like a ',
 '; the more you chase it, the more it will elude you, but if you turn your attention to other things, it will come and sit softly on your shoulder.” —\xa0',
 '99.\xa0“When it is obvious that goals can’t be reached, don’t adjust the goals, but adjust the action steps.” —\xa0',
 '100. “There may be people who have more talent than you, but there’s no excuse for anyone to work harder than you do – and I believe that.” — ',
 '101. “Don’t be afraid to fail. It’s not the end of the world, and in many ways, it’s the first step toward learning something and getting better at it.” —',
 '102.\xa0“Life is very interesting… in the end, some of your greatest pains, become your greatest strengths.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '103. “I think if you live in a black-and-white world, you’re gonna suffer a lot. I used to be like that. But I don’t believe that anymore.” –\xa0',
 '104.\xa0“I don’t believe in happy endings, but I do believe in happy travels, because ultimately, you die at a very young age, or you live long enough to watch your friends die. It’s a mean thing, life.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '105.\xa0“It’s never too late – never too late to start over, never too late to be happy.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '106.\xa0“You’re only human. You live once and life is wonderful, so eat the damned red velvet cupcake.” –\xa0',
 '107.\xa0“A lot of people give up just before they’re about to make it. You know you never know when that next obstacle is going to be the last one.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '(',
 ')',
 '108. “Be nice to people on the way up, because you may meet them on the way down.” –\xa0',
 '109.\xa0“I believe you make your day. You make your life. So much of it is all perception, and this is the form that I built for myself. I have to accept it and work within those compounds, and it’s up to me.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '110.\xa0“The minute that you’re not learning I believe you’re dead.”\xa0–\xa0',
 '111.\xa0“Life’s tough, but it’s tougher when you’re stupid.” –\xa0',
 '112.\xa0“Take up one idea. Make that one idea your life — think of it, dream of it, live on that idea. Let the brain, muscles, nerves, every part of your body be full of that idea, and just leave every other idea alone. This is the way to success.” —\xa0',
 '113. “I guess it comes down to a simple choice, really. Get busy living or get busy dying.” — ',
 '114. “When we strive to become better than we are, everything around us becomes better too.” —\xa0 ',
 '115. “There are three things you can do with your life: You can waste it, you can spend it, or you can invest it. The best use of your life is to invest it in something that will last longer than your time on Earth.” —\xa0',
 '116. “You only pass through this life once, you don’t come back for an encore.” —\xa0',
 '117.\xa0“In the long run, the sharpest weapon of all is a kind and gentle spirit.” —\xa0',
 '118.\xa0“You’re not defined by your past; you’re prepared by it. You’re stronger, more experienced, and you have greater ',
 '.” —\xa0',
 '119.\xa0“We become not a melting pot but a beautiful mosaic. Different people, different beliefs, different yearnings, different hopes, different dreams.” —\xa0',
 '120.\xa0“Nothing is more honorable than a grateful heart.” —\xa0',
 '121. “Once you figure out who you are and what you love about yourself, I think it all kinda falls into place.” — ',
 '122. “Happy is the man who can make a living by his hobby.” —\xa0',
 '123.\xa0“Just disconnect. Once in a day sometime, sit silently and from all connections disconnect yourself.” —\xa0',
 '124.\xa0“Be where you are; otherwise you will miss your life.” —\xa0',
 '125.\xa0“Living an experience, a particular fate, is accepting it fully.” —\xa0',
 '126.\xa0“The more you praise and celebrate your life, the more there is in life to celebrate.” —\xa0',
 '127. “Your image isn’t your character. Character is what you are as a person.” — ',
 '128.\xa0“Football is like life, it requires perseverance, self-denial, hard work sacrifice, dedication and respect for authority.” —',
 '129.\xa0“As you know, life is an echo; we get what we give.” —\xa0',
 '130. “There are no regrets in life, just lessons.” — ',
 '131.\xa0“I believe that nothing in life is unimportant every moment can be a beginning.” —\xa0',
 '132.\xa0“Find people who will make you better.” —\xa0',
 '133.\xa0“As my knowledge of things grew I felt more and more the delight of the world I was in.” —\xa0',
 '134. “Benjamin Franklin was a humanitarian that dedicated his life to making contributions to all humans. He had a clear purpose for himself: improve the human race.” —\xa0',
 '135. “You cannot control everything that happens to you; you can only control the way you respond to what happens. In your response is your power.” — ',
 '136.\xa0“Don’t allow your past or present condition to control you. It’s just a process that you’re going through to get you to the next level.” – ',
 '137.\xa0“You will meet two kinds of people in life: ones who build you up and ones who tear you down. But in the end, you’ll thank them both.” — ',
 '138.\xa0“My mission in life is not merely to survive, but to thrive; and to do so with some passion, some compassion, some humor, and some style.” – ',
 '139.\xa0“If we don’t change, we don’t grow. If we don’t grow, we aren’t really living.” – ',
 '140.\xa0“You choose the life you live. If you don’t like it, it’s on you to change it because no one else is going to do it for you.” –',
 '141. “It is impossible to live without failing at something, unless you live so cautiously, that you might as well not have lived at all – in which case you fail by default.” — ',
 '142.\xa0“Life doesn’t require that we be the best, only that we try our best.” – ',
 '143.\xa0“The way I see it, every life is a pile of good things and bad things. The good things don’t always soften the bad things, but vice versa, the bad things don’t always spoil the good things and make them unimportant.” – ',
 '144.\xa0“Life isn’t about waiting for the storm to pass, it’s about learning to dance in the rain.” – ',
 '145.\xa0“I enjoy life when things are happening. I don’t care if it’s good things or bad things. That means you’re alive.” – ',
 '146.\xa0“There’s more to life than basketball. The most important thing is your ',
 ' and taking care of each other and loving each other no matter what.” – ',
 '147. “Today, you have 100% of your life left.” – ',
 '148.\xa0“Nobody who ever gave his best regretted it.” – ',
 '149.\xa0“Make each day your masterpiece.” – ',
 '150.\xa0“You can’t put a limit on anything. The more you dream, the farther you get.” –']
```

**So you require `response.css('p:nth-child(n+6)::text').getall()`**

`getall()` returns a list whereas `get()` and `extract()` returns only first data.

***Your code must look like this:***

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        datas=response.css('p')
        for data in datas:
            quote = (data.css('p:nth-Child(n+6)::text').get()).replace('\xa0','') if (data.css('p:nth-Child(n+6)::text').get()) else ''
            author = data.css('strong::text').get().replace('\xa0','') if data.css('strong::text').get() else ''
            Merged=quote+author
            yield {'Quote':Merged}
```

Comment: how did u find css selector in developer tool.. there is only p tag and strong tag for every quotes, can u tell me how that came ?

Comment: how did u wrote this line p:nth-child(n+6) ?explain me I didn't get that.

Comment: i got it above comment that that line code, I think might this one also use right soup.select(
        'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p')] in beautifulsoup web scraping,, if u have any idea about can u explain me I hadn't now idea ?

Comment: how to remove before and after lines some quotes has something stuff...for example .\xa0“You can’t put a limit on anything. The more you dream, the farther you get.” –'] instead of that line should be like this ,"You can’t put a limit on anything. The more you dream, the farther you get."

Comment: `p:nth-child(n+6)` is there because the first quote starts from 6th `p`.

Comment: And if you are finding any difficulty in finding selectors you can find different tools
for eg: `SelectorGadget` in chrome.
*Please accept the answer if it was helpful for you.*

Comment: Getting eror,all_quotes = response.css('p:nth-Child(n+6)::text').strip('\xao').getall()
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape

Comment: That's not how you should do. Let me edit in the answer itself.

Comment: And there is not printing with author name which means this is in strong tag is there any to modify code?

Comment: You must scrape the authors' names from a different selector. Do you want it in the same string?

Comment: yes how it is ? We can separate author tag or same line wil be.

Comment: You can contact them at last or you can also extract them differently and save them in a JSON/CSV file.

Comment: that  not worked strip('\xa0')  agian its printing before and after quotes .Did u check it before? its worked for u?

Comment: What  mistake is it?

Comment: `Strip()` only removes whitespaces so `replace()` must be use.

Comment: p:nth-child(6) > strong I find  this is we can write another css selector to print author name?

Comment: Yes, if you ment `p:nth-child(n+6)>strong`.

Comment: replace() also not working its showing error    quote.replace('')
TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
so,what 2 arguments should be

Comment: For that please refer to the ***Answer*** I have updated it there.

Comment: i think instead of p, p:nth-child(n+6) i should replace strong tag which is presents in author name to print?

Comment: The author's `strong` tag is inside `p` tag so `p:nth-child(n+6)>strong` perfectly works.
If you go for `strong` only you will get all the strong.

Comment: can u observe once output some quotes are without \xa0 and some quotes are with \xao . after modifying code there not printing som e quotes missing

Comment: I have edited the answer check it, once again!

Comment: I went through this p:nth-child(n+6)>strong not printing author  and i tried this way also  author = response.css('strong:nth-child(n+6)::text').getall() not printing

Comment: Did you yield it? It's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Yaa Ii yield it ..I mean I add author in yield

Comment: Yaa Ii yield it ..I mean I add author in yield

Comment: No not printing autor names ,I think might be there is another way to write? That line

Comment: I want to  print quotes  everything line by line .I think (\n ) might be used in order to print ?? and if its correct where should I put in code line \n

Comment: ***Please accept the answer if it was helpful for you.***

Comment: I accept answer ..and i want to know print line by line in order quotes

Comment: Am Not sure of that in scrapy... I always use CSV so never tried it.

Comment: i want to print quotes and authors same line like this 150. “You can’t put a limit on anything. The more you dream, the farther you get.” – Michael Phelps. otherwise there is problem there printing unwanted strong tags also

Comment: some quotes merging and some quotes not merging author name?